# How to make pyLightning aware of the batch_size of a HeteroData object when converting a Geometric project to Lightning

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning, pytorch-dataloader, pytorch-geometric

I'm trying to get more familiar with the PyTorch ecosystem, and in particular with Geometric and Lightning.

I've found a nice example of [Link Prediction on Heterogeneous Networks](https://medium.com/@pytorch_geometric/link-prediction-on-heterogeneous-graphs-with-pyg-6d5c29677c70) using Geometric that I'm trying to convert to Lightning using the principles by W. Falcon (from Lightning itself) presented  in [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/from-pytorch-to-pytorch-lightning-a-gentle-introduction-b371b7caaf09).

I think I've completed the conversion successfully (the code included at the end of the question), but I'm still not able to run the Lightning version.

In particular, I'm getting the following error message:

```
Sanity Checking: 0it [00:00, ?it/s]
Sanity Checking DataLoader 0:   0%|          | 0/2 [00:00<?, ?it/s]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kckp856/Workspace/personal/medium/medium/light.py", line 214, in <module>
    trainer.fit(
  File "/Users/kckp856/Workspace/personal/medium/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 532, in fit
    call._call_and_handle_interrupt(
  File "/Users/kckp856/Workspace/personal/medium/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/call.py", line 43, in _call_and_handle_interrupt
    return trainer_fn(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/kckp856/Workspace/personal/medium/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 571, in _fit_impl
    self._run(model, ckpt_path=ckpt_path)
  File "/Users/kckp856/Workspace/personal/medium/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 980, in _run
    results = self._run_stage()
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/kckp856/Workspace/personal/medium/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 1021, in _run_stage
    self._run_sanity_check()
  File "/Users/kckp856/Workspace/personal/medium/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 1050, in _run_sanity_check
    val_loop.run()
  File "/Users/kckp856/Workspace/personal/medium/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/utilities.py", line 181, in _decorator
    return loop_run(self, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/kckp856/Workspace/personal/medium/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/evaluation_loop.py", line 115, in run
    self._evaluation_step(batch, batch_idx, dataloader_idx)
  File "/Users/kckp856/Workspace/personal/medium/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/evaluation_loop.py", line 376, in _evaluation_step
    output = call._call_strategy_hook(trainer, hook_name, *step_kwargs.values())
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/kckp856/Workspace/personal/medium/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/call.py", line 294, in _call_strategy_hook
    output = fn(*args, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/kckp856/Workspace/personal/medium/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/strategies/strategy.py", line 393, in validation_step
    return self.model.validation_step(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/kckp856/Workspace/personal/medium/medium/light.py", line 107, in validation_step
    self.log('train_loss', loss)
  File "/Users/kckp856/Workspace/personal/medium/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/core/module.py", line 493, in log
    results.log(
  File "/Users/kckp856/Workspace/personal/medium/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/connectors/logger_connector/result.py", line 406, in log
    batch_size = self._extract_batch_size(self[key], batch_size, meta)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/kckp856/Workspace/personal/medium/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/connectors/logger_connector/result.py", line 340, in _extract_batch_size
    batch_size = extract_batch_size(self.batch)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/kckp856/Workspace/personal/medium/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/utilities/data.py", line 72, in extract_batch_size
    for bs in _extract_batch_size(batch):
  File "/Users/kckp856/Workspace/personal/medium/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/utilities/data.py", line 51, in _extract_batch_size
    for sample in batch:
  File "/Users/kckp856/Workspace/personal/medium/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch_geometric/data/feature_store.py", line 513, in __iter__
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
```

If I understand correctly what is going on, `batch_size = extract_batch_size(self.batch)` is where Lightnening tries to determine the size of a batch.
It checks which class is the data loader inheriting from, and a few further different things once the parent is found.
In this case, it determines that our batch is `Iterable` and a `Mapping` (but not a `str`), it doesn't update the value of `batch` because it is actually NOT a `Mapping` (so, just an `Iterable`), but then it fails to iterate over the samples in the batch because - I believe - the `__iter__(self)` method is not implemented.

The `pl.LightningDataModule` returns 3 `LinkNeighborLoader` in which a `HeteroData` object is stored and a `batch_size=128` is specified.
If I try to:

```
data_module = MoviesDataModule()
data_module.prepare_data()
for batch in data_module.data_module.train_dataloader():
    print(batch)
```

I can iterate successfully, so the `__iter__(self)` method (or any equivalent) is actualy implemented.
In any case, the `batch_size` should be available as an attribute on any `LinkNeighborLoader` object.

I wonder whether the issue is caused by Lightning not being aware that it is dealing with Geometric DataLoaders or maybe it is caused by the way in which I loaded packages in my virtual environment?

I'm using Python 3.11.5 on MacOS (Intel); I've installed the default packages:

```
numpy
pandas
matplotlib
tqdm
```

defaulting to numpy==1.25.2, pandas==2.1.0, matplotlib==3.7.2, and tqdm==4.66.1.

Then I installed PyTorch (CPU) as suggested on the its website:

```
pip install torch torchvision torchaudio
```

which installed `torch==2.0.1`, `torchvision==0.15.2`, and `torchaudio==2.0.2`.

Then I proceeded with Geometric, using the new method instructed on its website:

```
pip install torch_geometric
```

which installed `torch-geometric==2.3.1`.

And eventually installed Lightning as simply as:

```
pip install lightning
```

resulting in `lightning==2.0.8` being installed.

With this setup, however, I couldn't run the Link Prediction code example because torch-sparse couldn't be found. I've found other people lamenting the issue and reporting that installing it the older way had worked for them, so:

```
pip install pyg_lib torch_scatter torch_sparse torch_cluster torch_spline_conv -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-2.0.0+cpu.html
```

which led to `pyg-lib==0.2.0+pt20`, `torch-scatter==2.1.1`, `torch-sparse==0.6.17`, `torch-cluster==1.6.1`, `torch-spline-conv==1.2.2`.

At this stage I could run the PyTorch Geometric example on Link Prediction.

**Any idea why my Lightning version of the Link Prediction example doesn't work?**

- **Did I do a mistake in the conversion?** (code below)
- **Do I have to setup the virtual environment in a different way? How?**
- **Or does `extract_batch_size(self.batch)` need to be fixed? How?** (test if the batch is HeteroData and find the batch_size in another way -- as suggested [in this post](https://github.com/Lightning-AI/lightning/issues/10576))

Many thanks in advance!

---

As promised, my code follows:

```
"""
Example from: https://medium.com/@pytorch_geometric/link-prediction-on-heterogeneous-graphs-with-pyg-6d5c29677c70
Conversion: https://towardsdatascience.com/from-pytorch-to-pytorch-lightning-a-gentle-introduction-b371b7caaf09
"""

import os.path
from typing import Any
from typing import Optional

import pandas as pd
import pytorch_lightning as pl
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch_geometric.transforms as T
from lightning.pytorch.utilities.types import EVAL_DATALOADERS
from lightning.pytorch.utilities.types import STEP_OUTPUT
from lightning.pytorch.utilities.types import TRAIN_DATALOADERS
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
from torch import Tensor
from torch_geometric.data import download_url
from torch_geometric.data import extract_zip
from torch_geometric.data import HeteroData
from torch_geometric.loader import LinkNeighborLoader
from torch_geometric.nn import SAGEConv
from torch_geometric.nn import to_hetero

url = 'https://files.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ml-latest-small.zip'

folder = "../data/external"
movies_path = f'{folder}/ml-latest-small/movies.csv'
ratings_path = f'{folder}/ml-latest-small/ratings.csv'


class GNN(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, hidden_channels):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = SAGEConv(hidden_channels, hidden_channels)
        self.conv2 = SAGEConv(hidden_channels, hidden_channels)

    def forward(self, x: Tensor, edge_index: Tensor) -> Tensor:
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x, edge_index))
        x = self.conv2(x, edge_index)
        return x


# Our final classifier applies the dot-product between source and destination
# node embeddings to derive edge-level predictions:
class Classifier(pl.LightningModule):
    def forward(self, x_user: Tensor, x_movie: Tensor, edge_label_index: Tensor) -> Tensor:
        # Convert node embeddings to edge-level representations:
        edge_feat_user = x_user[edge_label_index[0]]
        edge_feat_movie = x_movie[edge_label_index[1]]
        # Apply dot-product to get a prediction per supervision edge:
        return (edge_feat_user * edge_feat_movie).sum(dim=-1)


class Model(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, hidden_channels, data):
        super().__init__()
        # Since the dataset does not come with rich features, we also learn two
        # embedding matrices for users and movies:
        self.movie_lin = torch.nn.Linear(20, hidden_channels)
        self.user_emb = torch.nn.Embedding(data["user"].num_nodes, hidden_channels)
        self.movie_emb = torch.nn.Embedding(data["movie"].num_nodes, hidden_channels)
        # Instantiate homogeneous GNN:
        self.gnn = GNN(hidden_channels)
        # Convert GNN model into a heterogeneous variant:
        self.gnn = to_hetero(self.gnn, metadata=data.metadata())
        self.classifier = Classifier()

    def forward(self, data: HeteroData) -> Tensor:
        x_dict = {
            "user": self.user_emb(data["user"].node_id),
            "movie": self.movie_lin(data["movie"].x) + self.movie_emb(data["movie"].node_id),
        }
        # `x_dict` holds feature matrices of all node types
        # `edge_index_dict` holds all edge indices of all edge types
        x_dict = self.gnn(x_dict, data.edge_index_dict)
        pred = self.classifier(
            x_dict["user"],
            x_dict["movie"],
            data["user", "rates", "movie"].edge_label_index,
        )
        return pred

    def configure_optimizers(self) -> Any:
        optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
        return optimizer

    def cross_entropy_loss(self, logits, labels):
        return F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, labels)

    def roc_auc_score(self, logits, labels):
        return roc_auc_score(labels, logits)

    def training_step(self, train_batch, batch_idx, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> STEP_OUTPUT:
        logits = self.forward(train_batch)
        labels = train_batch["user", "rates", "movie"].edge_label
        loss = self.cross_entropy_loss(logits, labels)
        self.log('train_loss', loss)
        return loss

    def validation_step(self, val_batch, batch_idx, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Optional[STEP_OUTPUT]:
        logits = self.forward(val_batch)
        labels = val_batch["user", "rates", "movie"].edge_label
        loss = self.cross_entropy_loss(logits, labels)
        self.log('train_loss', loss)


class MoviesDataModule(pl.LightningDataModule):

    def prepare_data(self) -> None:
        if not os.path.exists(movies_path) or not os.path.exists(ratings_path):
            extract_zip(download_url(url, folder), folder)

        movies_df = pd.read_csv(movies_path, index_col='movieId')
        genres = movies_df['genres'].str.get_dummies('|')
        movie_feat = torch.from_numpy(genres.values).to(torch.float)
        assert movie_feat.size() == (9742, 20)  # 20 genres in total.

        ratings_df = pd.read_csv(ratings_path)
        unique_user_id = ratings_df['userId'].unique()
        unique_user_id = pd.DataFrame(data={
            'userId': unique_user_id,
            'mappedID': pd.RangeIndex(len(unique_user_id)),
        })

        unique_movie_id = ratings_df['movieId'].unique()
        unique_movie_id = pd.DataFrame(data={
            'movieId': unique_movie_id,
            'mappedID': pd.RangeIndex(len(unique_movie_id)),
        })

        ratings_user_id = pd.merge(ratings_df['userId'], unique_user_id, left_on='userId', right_on='userId',
                                   how='left')
        ratings_user_id = torch.from_numpy(ratings_user_id['mappedID'].values)

        ratings_movie_id = pd.merge(ratings_df['movieId'], unique_movie_id, left_on='movieId', right_on='movieId',
                                    how='left')
        ratings_movie_id = torch.from_numpy(ratings_movie_id['mappedID'].values)

        edge_index_user_to_movie = torch.stack([ratings_user_id, ratings_movie_id], dim=0)
        assert edge_index_user_to_movie.size() == (2, 100836)

        self.data = HeteroData()
        self.data["user"].node_id = torch.arange(len(unique_user_id))
        self.data["movie"].node_id = torch.arange(len(movies_df))
        self.data["movie"].x = movie_feat
        self.data["user", "rates", "movie"].edge_index = edge_index_user_to_movie
        self.data = T.ToUndirected()(self.data)

        transform = T.RandomLinkSplit(
            num_val=0.1,
            num_test=0.1,
            disjoint_train_ratio=0.3,
            neg_sampling_ratio=2.0,
            add_negative_train_samples=False,
            edge_types=("user", "rates", "movie"),
            rev_edge_types=("movie", "rev_rates", "user"),
        )
        self.train_data, self.val_data, self.test_data = transform(self.data)

    def train_dataloader(self) -> TRAIN_DATALOADERS:
        edge_label_index = self.train_data["user", "rates", "movie"].edge_label_index
        edge_label = self.train_data["user", "rates", "movie"].edge_label

        return LinkNeighborLoader(
            data=self.train_data,
            num_neighbors=[20, 10],
            neg_sampling_ratio=2.0,
            edge_label_index=(("user", "rates", "movie"), edge_label_index),
            edge_label=edge_label,
            batch_size=128,
            shuffle=True,
        )

    def val_dataloader(self) -> EVAL_DATALOADERS:
        edge_label_index = self.val_data["user", "rates", "movie"].edge_label_index
        edge_label = self.val_data["user", "rates", "movie"].edge_label

        return LinkNeighborLoader(
            data=self.val_data,
            num_neighbors=[20, 10],
            neg_sampling_ratio=2.0,
            edge_label_index=(("user", "rates", "movie"), edge_label_index),
            edge_label=edge_label,
            batch_size=128,
            shuffle=False,
            # num_workers=16,
        )

    def test_dataloader(self) -> EVAL_DATALOADERS:
        edge_label_index = self.test_data["user", "rates", "movie"].edge_label_index
        edge_label = self.test_data["user", "rates", "movie"].edge_label

        return LinkNeighborLoader(
            data=self.test_data,
            num_neighbors=[20, 10],
            neg_sampling_ratio=2.0,
            edge_label_index=(("user", "rates", "movie"), edge_label_index),
            edge_label=edge_label,
            batch_size=128,
            shuffle=True,
        )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    data_module = MoviesDataModule()
    data_module.prepare_data()

    model = Model(hidden_channels=64, data=data_module.data)

    trainer = pl.Trainer(max_epochs=6)
    trainer.fit(
        model,
        train_dataloaders=data_module.train_dataloader(),
        val_dataloaders=data_module.val_dataloader(),
    )

    print('Done.')
```